# Linux Copy recursively

Tags: linux, centos, cp

Every-time I copy recursively I always end up with httpdocs folder instead of the files within in public_html.

For example I might run something like:

```
cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/httpdocs
```

I always end up with /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/httpdocs/httpdocs when all I am trying to do is move a website from one user to another.

Comment: did the target folder already exist?

Comment: `cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/`

Comment: Yes it always exists as I am usually updating a website.

Comment: And I thoughti t would be what you have said devnull but I always end up having an httpdocs folder within the httpdocs folder when I just want to overide the website files with new files that I have copied elsewhere to work on etc.

Comment: Offtopic, unless this is part of a larger script or something like that. Belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just want to "push" your local website without getting offline long, you can use a temporary dir.

```
TODAY=$(date +%y%m%d)
NEWCODE=/var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/docs_${TODAY}
OLDCODE=/var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/docs_old
rm -rf ${NEWCODE}
cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs ${NEWCODE} || exit 1
# some checks ?
cd /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/ || exit 1
mv httpdocs ${OLDCODE} || exit 1
mv ${NEWCODE} httpdocs
```

Between the moves you will be unavailable. When that is a problem, you might want to make a work_in_progress.html file, rename that file to httpdocs/index.html, remove all other files and copy the new files after this (the correct index.html file as the last one).
But this seems to fancy, stick with the short hickup in the solution above.

Comment: Hey Walter, I don't wish to do that, I usually copy the whole website to another domain we have and work on it there (on the same linux server) so I just want to copy the files back. I always end up with the httpdocs/httpdocs problem. Why doesn't anyone understand my question it is a simple mistake I keep making I am sure of it just need to add a . or a * to my cp command and I think I am done. I also remember a dev warning me about something to do with . or * in the past.

Comment: Something like cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/* /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/httpdocs
You can also look at rsync.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell copy to treat the destination directory as a file instead of as a directory (into which to copy the folder that you've listed as your source). Which means you need the `-T` option.

Alternatively you could use a source of `/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/*` if that glob captures all the files you actually care about. That should work too.

Comment: I think my command should be something like this: \cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/newsite/httpdocs/* /var/www/vhosts/livewebsite/httpdocs But I have been warned using the wildcard can cause issues. It could even be \cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/newsite/httpdocs/.* or . to /var/www/vhosts/livewebsite/httpdocs I just don't want to end up with /var/www/vhosts/livewebsite/httpdocs/httpdocs I just want the files from /newsite/httpdocs to go into /livewebsite/httpdocs overwriting any files with the same name etc. I know how to manually mv things from . to .. etc but it's not a solution I am happy with.

Comment: I just edited my post to include the glob I meant to include in the first place. I'm not sure what happened there. Using a wildcard can't "cause issues" but it does have specific operating rules that you need to account for (it won't match `.dotfiles` for example). The `-T` option to `cp`, however, is more what you want if your `cp` has it.

Answer (score 0):

Wat do you want when a file exists under aontherwebsite and not in the source website?
I think you want anotherwebsite to be an exact copy, so make sure the old files are removed first.

```
rm -r /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/httpdoc
cp -rpf /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs /var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/httpdoc
```

Edit: anotherwebsite should stay available.
The general trick is using tar:

```
tar cf - * | ( cd /target; tar xf -)
```

In your case:

```
TARGET=/var/www/vhosts/anotherwebsite/httpdoc
cd /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs || exit 1
mkdir -p ${TARGET}
[ -d ${TARGET} ] || exit 1
tar cf - * | ( cd ${TARGET}; tar xf -)
```

I added "|| exit 1" to be sure you do not copy from the wrong dir and ${TARGET} is a dir.
You still have 3 challenges:
1) How do you delete files you do not use anymore (yesterday_special_action.html)
2) should you copy images first, for customers opening new pages before the images are copied
3) what website do you have if the copy/tar fails after copying a part (disk full)

I will post a new answer for solving these challenges.

Comment: I don't wish to remove the old files first on a live website because there site will be down for a short time while I cp the new files to the web root of the live website. I just want to cp the new files and overwrite all of the files, the issue I am having is I usually end up with a folder within the live root (httpdocs) called httpdocs so it looks like httpdocs/httpdocs when it should copy the contents of httpdocs and overwrite them into just httpdocs of the live website not copy the folder httpdocs and place it inside httpdocs ending up with httpdocs/httpdocs